# Existence of second partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

let $f: \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$ be a continuous function.

Then can the derivative $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \, \partial y}$ can exist without

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ existing?

I have no idea how to look for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take any non-differentiable continuous function of $x$ like $f(x,y)=|x|$.  As a function of two variables it is constant in $y$.  But it is not differentiable at any point where $x=0$.  But it's constant in the $y$ direction so if you take the $y$ derivative first you get the zero function, which you can then take the $x$ derivative of and you just get the zero function again.  If you want a function where it's true for all $(x,y)$ then use the Weierstrass function of one variable that's continuous but nowhere differentiable and think of it as a function of two variables, constant in $y$.  For example $f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\cos(15^n\pi x)$.

Comment: is that function continuous?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that.  Let me edit